# Spring Data JPA, hibernate: update all query and SET value by selecting from another table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is the following SQL possible in a JPA query? I tried but the actual SQL hibernate runs doesn't seem right.

This is the SQL i want to write as JPA query;

```
UPDATE movie m SET average_rating = COALESCE((SELECT AVG(stars) FROM rating r WHERE r.movie_id = m.id), 0);
```

This is the JPA query;

```
@Query("UPDATE Movie m SET m.averageRating = COALESCE((SELECT AVG(r.stars) FROM Rating r WHERE r.movie = m), 0)")
```

And what hibernate says;

```
Hibernate:
    insert
    into
        HT_Movie
        select
            movie0_.id as id
        from
            Movie movie0_
Hibernate:
    update
        Movie
    set
        average_rating=coalesce((select
            avg(rating1_.stars)
        from
            Rating rating1_
        where
            rating1_.movie_id=id),
        0)
    where
        (
            id
        ) IN (
            select
                id
            from
                HT_Movie
        )
```

so there seems to be an additional where being added by hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("UPDATE Movie m SET m.averageRating = COALESCE((SELECT AVG(r.stars) FROM Rating r WHERE r.movie = m), 0)")
```

This is 100% correct.
And *hibernate* works correctly as well.
*Hibernate* works in this way:

1. Create a temporary table `HT_Movie` and insert the ids of Movie table.
2. Create the *JPA* query as a whole where
3. Compare abstracting ids from `HT_Movie` t enforce more speed in update processing

And this is not new *hibernate* always fabricates queries.

Comment: ah ok, I might have missed something somewhere, when I check the average_rating column it is not updated.

Comment: I think its a transactional issue, but the save methods from the CRUDRepository/JpaRepository are fine. I will need to take a closer look.

Comment: How will you check that?

Comment: it's the update all 'WHERE r.movie =m', if I change the query to its 'WHERE r.movie = :movie' and I pass in the movie to be updated, so it selectively updates one movies' average rating, it works. the temporary table of ids it creates may be empty which explains why nothing get updated.

Comment: the solution i got would only work if i read out all the movie ids and then call the update repository method for each id, was hoping to get it it would update all in one query